# How to read a linked list from a txt file?

Tags: c, linked-list, txt

So i have a linked list, which i was able to save in a txt file. Now the question is how do i read this from the same file ? I tried every possible method I found on web and literally nothing is working.

I have 3 files: main, struct and function.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "struct.h"
#include "function.h"

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    while(go)
    {
        userChose=Menu();
        Bloc();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

struct.h:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char name[256];
    int  amount;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int go = 1;
int userChose = 0;
int n;
node * head = NULL;
```

and function.h:

```
int Menu()
{
    printf("\t\t\t--Menu--\n");
    printf("1. Create a linked list with n nodes.\n");
    printf("2. Show linked list.\n");
    printf("16. Save in txt.\n");
    printf("17. Read from txt.\n");
    int c;
    printf("\t\t\nOption: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    system("cls");
    return c;
}

node * CreateList()
{
    node * head = NULL;
    node * temp = NULL;
    node * ptr = NULL;
    printf("number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        getchar();
        gets(temp->Denumire);

        printf("amount: ");
        scanf("%d",&(temp->amount));

        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = head;
            while(ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next = temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void ShowList()
{
    node * p = head;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("---------------------------\n");
        printf("Name: %s\n",p->name);
        printf("Amount: %d\n",p->amount);
        printf("curr adress: %p\n",p);
        printf("next adress: %p\n",p->next);
        printf("---------------------------\n");
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void Save()
{
    FILE * file = fopen("liste.txt","w");
    node * p = head;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(file,"---------------------------\n");
        fprintf(file,"name: %s\n",p->name);
        fprintf(file,"amount: %d\n",p->amount);
        fprintf(file,"adress: %p\n",p);
        fprintf(file,"next adress: %p\n",p->next);
        fprintf(file,"---------------------------\n");
        p=p->next;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

and at the end:

```
void PressAnyKey()
{
    printf("\n--Apasati pentru a continua--\n");
    _getch();
    system("cls");
}

void Bloc()
{
    switch (userChose)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            head = CreateList();
            PressAnyKey();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            ShowList();
            PressAnyKey();
        }
        break;
case 16:
        {
            Save();
            printf("List saved in txt.");
            PressAnyKey();
        }
        break;
    case 17:
        {
            Read();
            PressAnyKey();
        }
        break;
case 0:
        {
            go = 0;
            system("cls");
            printf("Exit done.\n");
            _getch();
        }
        break;
    default:
        system("cls");
        printf("Error\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried to use fread() but it seems this is not running at all.

Comment: You probably want `scanf` rather than read. (The title of this question threw me. Its probably more accurate to say you serialized the data in your link list into a text file in your own customized way--I had thought for a moment you were trying to read back binary from a text file).

Comment: OT: Don't _define_ functions in a .h like you do in function.h. Instead define then im a function.c and just declare them in function.h by providing a prototype. Anyway I'm missing `Read()`. Am I overlooking it or what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this one, but it's not working:
`void Read()
{
node * p = head;
 node n1;
 FILE * file=fopen("liste.txt","r");
 while(frea(&s1,sizeof(node),1,file))
    {
 if(p==NULL)
 {
 p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
p->name=n1.name;
 p->amount=n1.amount;
  p->next=NULL;
head=p;
 }
else
  {
 while(p->next != NUILL)
 { p=p->next;
  } p->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));p->next->name=n1.name;p->next->amount=n1.amount;p->next->next=NULL; }} fclose(file);}
`

Answer (score 3):

> how do i read this from the same file ?

Pointers are meaningful only in the context of one execution of the program.  It is rarely useful to write pointer values to persistent storage as you are doing, and almost never useful to read pointer values *from* any external source.

So don't.  Save only the node data (name and amount, in your case),  not the self or next pointers.  Do this in a way that indicates the order of the nodes, which is ordinarily just by writing the data sequentially according to list order, as you already are doing.

To read that back in any execution of the program, do much as you already do when initially creating the list, but instead of inputting the node data interactively, read it from the file (probably `fgets()` is a better choice for that than `fscanf()`).  Among other things, this means dynamically allocating a new node for each item.  You will need to make a few adjustments to handle the file format you've chosen, but that's shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: can you please explain how the function should look like ?

i have one where even the first while is not working

Comment: `void Read(){  node * p = head;   node n1;  FILE * file=fopen("liste.txt","r");
    while(frea(&s1,sizeof(node),1,file))
    {
        if(p==NULL)
        {
            p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            p->name=n1.name;
            p->amount=n1.amount;
            p->next=NULL;
            head=p;
        }   else   {
        while(p->next != NUILL)
        {
       p=p->next;
            }
            p->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            p->next->name=n1.name;
            p->next->amount=n1.amount;
            p->next->next=NULL;} }  fclose(file);}`

Comment: @blinamx, I'm not sure where you came up with the idea of using a binary read (`fread()`) to input the data from your file.  I don't think you've really grasped how parallel the read-from-file case is to the interactive input case for the file format you've chosen.  I *know* you have disregarded my recommendation to use `fgets()` to read from the file, and it wasn't by using `fscanf()` instead, which I at least would have understood.

Comment: i understand that i have to use `fgets()` , but i can't understand how it should look similar to the creation with `gets` instead.

Comment: @blinamx, I am intentionally avoiding writing the function for you, as that would rob you of the benefit of working the exercise.  But there are three main things that differ: (1) you will know you've reached the end of the list when you reach the end of the file, not by knowing in advance how many nodes to expect; (2) you'll use `fgets()` to read data from the file; and (3) you'll need to parse out the delimiters and field titles (or alternatively, revise your file format to omit those).